# Woocommerce thumbnail over title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So i have a website where i want the page that shows my products like this
[image]

1. Thumbnail
2. Title
3. Description

at the moment it is like
[image]

1. Title
2. woocommerce_archive_description (which is both the description and thumbnail)

this is the page template:

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header('shop');
?>
<div class="woo-leasing" id="woo-leasing" >
<?php
$term = get_queried_object();
$hasChilds = wooTermHasChildren($term->term_id);

if (!empty($term) && $term->count > 0) {
    $args = array('term' => $term);
    wc_get_template('content-leasing-single.php', $args);
} elseif (!empty($term) && $hasChilds) {
    do_action('woocommerce_archive_description');
    echo '<h1 class="page-title">';
    woocommerce_page_title();
    echo '</h1>';
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    woocommerce_product_subcategories();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();



} elseif (!woocommerce_product_subcategories(array('before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start(false), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end(false)))) {
    wc_get_template('loop/no-products-found.php');
}
?>
</div>
<?php get_footer('shop'); ?>
```

As i am inexperienced i believe this is the code to manipulate.

```
    do_action('woocommerce_archive_description');
    echo '<h1 class="page-title">';
    woocommerce_page_title();
    echo '</h1>';
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    woocommerce_product_subcategories();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

i want to seperate the woocommerce_archive_description so i could do something like this.

```
    woocommerce_page_thumbnail();
    echo '<h1 class="page-title">';
    woocommerce_page_title();
    echo '</h1>';
    woocommerce_page_description();
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    woocommerce_product_subcategories();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

I hope you understand my question, and i would be happy if you could help me to approach this issue.